# Is it possible to add different views for a ListView at runtime?

Tags: android, listview, android-tablelayout, listadapter

I ran into a situation where I need to make each item of a `ListView` have different views. For example,
the first item might have a `TextView` and an `ImageView`, where the second item might have a `Button` and a `TextView`.
My initial attempt was using a table layout nested inside an item adapter, but it doesn't work.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ItemViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_activity_item, null);
            holder = new ItemViewHolder();
            holder.textViewText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_activity_item_xml_textview_user_name);
            holder.textViewText2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_activity_item_xml_textview_user_where);
            holder.table = (TableLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_activity_item_xml_tablelayout_activity_table);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ItemViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textViewText.setText(items.get(position));
        holder.textViewText2.setText(items.get(position));

        // add a new row
        TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
        row.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams(android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ImageView i = new ImageView(context);
        TextView t = new TextView(context);
        t.setText("Some texts");
        row.addView(i);
        row.addView(t);
        holder.table.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        return convertView;
    }
```

Each time the list got loaded, the table got modified accordingly. So the number of items keeps increasing. So my question is, is there a way to handle this situation? What can I do to make a dynamic `ListView` in which I can add another widget at runtime for each item? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set convertView = null at the start of method. it will work.